# No sound at all in elementary OS Loki

Tags: sound, ubuntu

I installed Pot Player using Wine in Elementary OS 0.4 Loki, it didn't work so I uninstalled it. The icon was still in the applications list, so I removed Wine thinking that it might help, I followed [this forum](http://sourcedigit.com/10018-completely-uninstallremove-wine-ubuntu-14-04/). After that I could hear no sound, no sound at all, no sound in vlc, videos and other players and no notification sounds at all.  I can't even hear any sound in sound test, even in bluetooth speakers or headphones. How to get it back? I'm running Elementary OS Loki.

Comment: Have you tried installing pavucontrol? `sudo apt-get update` and afterwards 
`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Comment: You might want to check which output device is selected in _System Settings/Sound_

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 of this doc at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
includes installation and starting pavucontrol and helped me restore sound on a Dell Lattitude laptop.  I had system sounds like trash and test front left/ front right but Noise Music player and videos on the browser did not have audio.

Answer (score 0):

In Elementary Loki systems settings I no longer have Sound. Not sure what I installed to loose it. Anyway **Jorge R. Marin's** solution above to install **pavucontrol** via Terminal got sound back on my Toshiba Satellite laptop running on Elementary Loki. Thank you Jorge.